# Run a macro in Access which take information from internet and enter them in fields

Tags: database, forms, vba, ms-access

**Situation :**

Excel Worksheet : I made a code on VBA which goes through each cell of a column, take the DHL Tracking Number inside of it, searches for more information about this one on the DHL website and then pasts important information ( last status and date of last update) in 2 separated columns. That part is fine and works, but now I am trying to apply this exact same procedure on a Access Form.

**Issue :**

Access : I am trying to find a way to go through each record of a form's specific field, copy the information it includes, then do the internet part as mentioned above, and write the 2 important information in 2 other fields in that same form.

**The issue is that I don't manage to go through to each record of a form's specific field firstly.**

Any ideas ?

Let me know if you need more information or if it's not clear.

**EDIT :** [My form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVQA8.png) is bound to a table. I am talking above about a form, but it would be totally fine to find a solution which could be applied on the Access table it is bound to also. This is a datasheet form which contains multiple records. The reason I first made a table was to set lots of complex validation rules for most of the fields and also for some updatequeries purposes.

For your information the VBA code is the following :

```
 Sub Main()

Dim AWB_Number As Double
Dim internet As Object
Dim path As String
Dim IEDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim objShell As Object
Dim IE_count As Integer
Dim La_Date As String
Dim Le_Texte As String
Dim i As Integer

Columns("V").NumberFormat = "General"
For i = 4 To Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' A CHANGER !!!
'MsgBox TypeName(Range("Q" & i).Value)

    If TypeName(Range("Q" & i).Value) = "Double" And Range("Q" & i).Value <> 0 Then
    AWB_Number = Range("Q" & i).Value
    Else: GoTo Laa
    End If
    'Cells(13, 3).Value = 0
    'Cells(14, 3).Value = 0
    'Cells(15, 3).Value = 0
    'New InternetExplorer
        path = "http://www.dhl.co.uk/en/express/tracking.html"

        Set internet = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        internet.Visible = True
        internet.navigate path
        Do While internet.readyState <> 4
        Loop
        Set IEDoc = internet.document

        'MsgBox IEDoc.getElementsByName("AWB").Length' 1
        IEDoc.getElementsByName("AWB")(0).Value = AWB_Number

        'MsgBox IEDoc.getElementsByClassName("tracking-button").Length' 1
        IEDoc.getElementsByClassName("tracking-button")(0).Click

        Do While internet.readyState <> 4
        Loop
        Set IEDoc = internet.document

    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1.5) 'Call Warte_mal
    'On Error GoTo Ici
        'MsgBox IEDoc.getElementsByClassName("result-checkpoints show result-has-pieces").Length '1
        'MsgBox IEDoc.getElementsByClassName("result-checkpoints show result-has-pieces")(0).getElementsByTagName("th")(0).innerText ' Thursday, October 20, 2016
        On Error Resume Next
        'If IEDoc.getElementsByClassName("result-checkpoints show result-has-pieces")(0).getElementsByTagName("th")(0).innerText Is Nothing Then
       'GoTo Ici
         La_Date = IEDoc.getElementsByClassName("result-checkpoints show result-has-pieces")(0).getElementsByTagName("th")(0).innerText
    'End If
       Le_Texte = IEDoc.getElementsByClassName("result-checkpoints show result-has-pieces")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText
        Range("R" & i).Value = La_Date & " " & Le_Texte
        La_Date = ""
        Le_Texte = ""

        Call Filtre(Range("R" & i).Value, i)
Ici:
          internet.Quit
    Set internet = Nothing
Laa:
Next i

'Range("R:R").EntireColumn.Delete
Range("T:T").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("V:V").EntireColumn.AutoFit
MsgBox "Congratulations Dragos, you've officially been replaced !"

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use Excel VBA on Access. Databases do not have rows and columns, they have records and fields.

Comment: Yes. I just editted the post with the proper terms. The issue remains the same though.

Comment: The terms are irrelevant. You are still trying to use Excel VBA on Access. It is all trying to read from an Excel spreadsheet, not an Access recordset.

Comment: But the code above is the one I used exclusively for the excel spreadsheet, of course it's not valid for Access. My question is how can I adapt it to Access ?

Comment: For your information, you can ( I did it in thid database as well) build your own macros in an Access module, but accessing to the information in an Access form is different, so that's where I need help.

Comment: You can't. You have to write Access VBA. The part that accesses the Internet can probably be used as is, but how to read data in Access and how to write data back is something you will have to learn to do and beyond the scope of a question.

Comment: *"The issue is that I don't manage to go through to each record of a form's specific field firstly."* .- This is unclear. Please [edit] your question to better convey what you are trying to accomplish. Also, if this is a "continuous form" (bound to a table and displaying multiple records at the same time) then you should mention that, too.

Comment: See edit for more details, I hope it makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

Range isn't inside Access' scope.  You need to open a dataset and iterate through each record.  So, something like:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT MyField FROM MyTable")

Do while rec.EOF = false
  'Use the Nz() function to check to see if there is a value
  If Nz(rec(0), 0) <> 0 Then
     AWB_Number = rec(0)
     'Do whatever else you do with this number.  Send it to DHL website
  Else
  End if
  rec.MoveNext
Loop

rec.close
db.close
```

This is "aircode"; untested and with generic info.  Change "MyField" to the field name in your table, etc...  And it may need some tweaks, but it's probably pretty close to what you need.

Comment: This code is missing critical parts (like actually reading a record or moving from record to record with `rec.MoveFirst` and `rec.MoveNext`. Also `Endif` should be `End If`. It also does not address the fact that the question is about reading data from a form, not from a table. There are also other major issues (like failing when zero is a valid value for `MyField`, making things unecessaitly obscure by using `rec(0)` instead of `rec!MyField`, not checking for no records returned)

Comment: "...Each record of a form's specific field...".  If you can do that without touching the table, I'll be impressed.  If you can find an instance of a DHL tracking number of zero, I'll be impressed.  The other two, I screwed up on, I've got 2 projects going at work and I offered the caveat that it may need tweaking.  I'll edit those.

Comment: Depending on the situation and what exactly he means, he could read either directly from the form controls or use the form's recordset property to iterate through. The main reason he would want to read from a form is user input and we don't know if the form is bound to a table or not.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm going through this right now, but first issue is that the count property of recordsets shows 0 when I check it in the Watch window of my Current database, so I can't use that method. I only can access to the right form by going through the "Container" of the database but then it only displays me the information about the form and I can't access to its fields